# Python if statement gone wrong. Whats wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, printing, user-input

I don't understand what's wrong with my code here. Can someone help me pls? I've been trying to solve it all morning.

```
question = input("Choose from 0 to 1 : ") 
mylist = ["Mark", "Jenny"] 
if question == 0: 
    print(mylist[0], "is your new friend") 
elif question == 1: 
    print(mylist[1], "is your new friend")
else:
    print("I said choose from 0 to 1")
```

Comment: Can you explain what and where is the error ?

Comment: The input() function returns a string, but you are checking against integers 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the data types:

input() returns a string but in your, if statement you're comparing a string "0" to an integer 0. Because of that else is always executed.

Concert the input() into int() like shown below:

```
question = int(input("Choose from 0 to 1 : "))
mylist = ["Mark", "Jenny"] 
if question == 0: 
    print(mylist[0], "is your new friend") 
elif question == 1: 
    print(mylist[1], "is your new friend")
else:
    print("I said choose from 0 to 1")
```

Comment: Im stupid I guess. I should have seen it. Thank you

Comment: happens with everyone, This is how you remember these things after countless times making this mistake!